# What the meaning of mark a lambda capturing this as mutable in C++?

Tags: c++

I found following code in [a raft implementation](https://github.com/datatechnology/cornerstone/blob/master/src/raft_server.cxx).

```
[this](ptr<resp_msg>& resp, const ptr<rpc_exception>& e) mutable {
          this->handle_peer_resp(resp, e);
}
```

When we capture this in a lambda expression, we have already be allowed to modify the value of member or call member function (as shown following).

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  int a;
  A() { a = 0; }
  std::function<void(int)> func = [this](const int & b) mutable { a = 10; this->print(b); };
  void callFunc() { func(1); }

  void print(const int & b) { std::cout << a << " " << b << std::endl; }
};

int main() {
  A a;
  a.callFunc();
  return 0;
}
```

Why do they use mutable in this lambda function ?

Comment: Nothing that I can see. It's not mutating the lambda at all so making it `mutable` seems unnecessary

Comment: which standard are you using ? Capturing `this` underwent some changes

Comment: It's because without `mutable` `this` is `const` and inside lambda a member `a` of `this` is changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this

```cpp
std::function<void(int)> func = [this](const int & b) mutable {
    a = 10;
    this->print(b);
};
```

there is nothing mutating the lambda and removing `mutable` would be the reasonable thing to do.

I therefore made a [pull request](https://github.com/datatechnology/cornerstone/pull/57) in the Cornerstone repo to remove `mutable` from the lambdas that don't mutate, which has been approved, so now the confusing `mutable`s aren't there anymore.

Comment: Unless method somehow got a const overload, calling it requires mutable object

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Do you mean if `print` has a `const` qualified overload? I'm not sure I follow what you mean exactly. Can you show what you mean on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1aWYofWax)?

Comment: It lloks like a break in the meaning of const object: without `mutable` `this` is `const` but inside `this` is changed by `a = 10;` and also `print` is not `const` ... despite that for the compiler everything is fine [article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/mutable)

Comment: @MarcoBeninca `this` is a pointer and we're not assigning a new value to it. Compare to `[foo=this](const int& b) { foo->a = 10; foo = nullptr; }` - that would require the lambda to be `mutable` because `foo = nullptr;` mutates the lambda while `foo->a = 10;` does not.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it makes sense

Comment: In orignal type initialzed by lambda isn't std::function and it's not how its traits are used through whole framework of cornerstone, it's a nested type from boost's `async_result`, aliased as `rpc_handler`. By look of it `mutable` there was used for const-correctness in that particular spot. Or just as a marker that this handler can change something. Next to it are alternate initializators which do not use mutable lambda when they initialize executors (std::function in that case).

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie So, what you are saying is that the supposedly [mre] in the question isn't actually mimicing what's done in the code following the external link?

Comment: Unclear. I'm not at computer to check what it is defined as in `boost::asio`, I'm typing this from a phone with physical keys, but cornerstone's code (project at provided link) there is complex and interconnected (factory methods, subsystem and something). It cuould be purely a mnemonic keyword, kind of self-documenting code. Once we used `override` for same purpose

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Without digging deep into the code, I cloned the repo, removed `mutable` and it compiled fine. Perhaps it's meant to document something but it'd be a pretty bad way of doing it i.m.o. `override` documents and verifies that we're overriding. Making something `mutable` that doesn't need to mutate is something else.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I think it was just a mistake to make them `mutable`. I made a pull request to remove `mutable` which was approved with no fuzz. :-)

Answer (score 0):

it should be a historical issue, this code has been refactored couple times, and mutable looks not necessary now, can you submit a pr for this?

Comment: I already did and it's been approved :-)

Answer (score -1):

well, after digging it little bit, this is what I found on
[Microsoft Documentations:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/lambda-expressions-in-cpp?view=msvc-170)

> The mutable keyword is used so that the body of the lambda expression can modify its copies of the external variables x and y, which the lambda expression captures by value. Because the lambda expression captures the original variables x and y by value, their values remain 1 after the lambda executes.

so basically marking a lambda expression as mutable allows it to access and mutate "change" the external variables if  needed.

Comment: _"mutate "change" the external variables if needed"_ - No, you came to the wrong conclusion. It can change external variables even without being `mutable`. It can't change its copies of the external variables unless being `mutable`.

Comment: You're mistaken. Lambda object by default is a const object, but to chane external variables you would use either reference or pointer - therefore you can change them. mutable kw here removes const qualifier